# Graphing $ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{{|x+1 \mid}^{n}+x^{2}}{|x|+x^{2n}} $

Tags: limits, graphing-functions

Graph: $$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{{|x+1 \mid}^{n}+x^{2}}{|x|+x^{2n}} 
$$

Here I tried first to resolve the limit, dividing by ${x}^{2n}$ in both numerator and plugging in $\infty$ I obtain the limit to be zero for all values of $x$. But when it tried to graph it using a graphing calculator I obtained the following graph (I put n=10000),[image]

Can anyone please point out my mistake?

Comment: You have not made a mistake. This seems to be some kind of floating-point error on the part of Desmos (the graphing software).

Comment: Don't you mean "...the limit to be zero for all values of $n$" and $n=10000$?

Comment: The limit is $0$ if $n>1$.

Comment: After dividing by $x^{2n}$, you seem to think that $\bigg(\frac{|x+1|}{x^2}\bigg)^n+\bigg(\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)^{n-1}$ goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ for any non-zero $x$, but this is not true. You need to compare $\frac{|x+1|}{x^2}$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}$ with $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case by case:

If $x>\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, then $x+1<x^2$ and we can divide by $x^{2n}$ to se that:

$$
\lim_n \frac{(x+1)^n + x^2}{x+(x^2)^n}=\lim_n \frac{(\frac{x+1}{x^2})^n + x^{2-2n}}{x^{1-2n}+1}=\frac{0+0}{0+1}=0
$$

If $0<x<\varphi$, then $x+1>x^2$ , thus

$$
\lim_n \frac{(x+1)^n + x^2}{x+(x^2)^n}=\lim_n \frac{(\frac{x+1}{x^2})^n + x^{2-2n}}{x^{1-2n}+1}=\frac{\infty+0}{0+1}=\infty
$$

If  $-1<x<0$, then $x^2<1$ and $0<x+1<1$, and the limit turns out to be:
$$
\lim_n \frac{(x+1)^n + x^2}{-x+(x^2)^n}=\frac{x^2}{-x}=-x
$$

If $-2<x<-1$, then $|x+1|<1$ and $x^2>1$, resulting in

$$
\lim_n \frac{|x+1|^n + x^2}{-x+(x^2)^n}=\frac{0+x^2}{-x+\infty}=0
$$

And finally, for $x<-2$ we can divide by $x^2$,
and taking into account that $\frac{|x+1|}{x^2}<1$ we get that

$$
\lim_n \frac{|x+1|^n + x^2}{-x+(x^2)^n}=\lim_n \frac{(\frac{-(x+1)}{x^2})^n + x^{2-2n}}{x^{1-2n}+1}=\frac{0+0}{0+1} = 0
$$

Maybe we could have considered the last two together, but I think that separating them helps conceptually.

Comment: For your $x>1$ case, $\left( \frac{x+1}{x}\right)^{n}$ does not converge to $1$.  The limit is infinite when $0<x<\varphi$, where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. This is because $|x+1| > 1$ and $|x+1| > x^{2}$.  The limit is zero for $x>\varphi$, and is $1$ when $x=\varphi$.

Comment: @SherwinLott that is so true. Let me change that.

Comment: The limit is $\frac 12$ when $x=-1$, and is $1$ when $x=\varphi$ where the latter was already pointed out.